# How do you add a scrollbar to a Panel control with many controls in windows form application?

Tags: winforms, controls, scrollbar, panel

How do you add a scrollbar to a Panel control with many controls in windows form application?

Comment: Dont' repost your question, edit your other one and you will get answers.

Answer (score 134):

Just set the `AutoScroll` property of your `Panel` to true and it will handle adding the scrollbars for you.

```
this.panel1.AutoScroll = true;
```

Comment: Bear in mind that your controls will need to be anchored to the Top of the Panel to cause Vertical scroll bars automatically, and the Left of the Panel to cause Horizontal scroll bars automatically. If Anchor is set to None that control will be ignored by AutoScroll. I tried to add this to the answer but it was rejected.

Comment: In addition, your controls shouldn't be docked in the panel or the scrollbar won't appear either.