# scrollbar doesn't appear in resize form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, resize

I have a form formstyle.none and I won't to make it re-sizable  so i use that code:

```
    const uint WM_NCHITTEST = 0x0084, WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200,
         HTLEFT = 10, HTRIGHT = 11, HTBOTTOMRIGHT = 17,
         HTBOTTOM = 15, HTBOTTOMLEFT = 16, HTTOP = 12,
         HTTOPLEFT = 13, HTTOPRIGHT = 14;
    Size formSize;
    Point screenPoint;
    Point clientPoint;
    Dictionary<uint, Rectangle> boxes;
    const int RHS = 10; // RESIZE_HANDLE_SIZE
    bool handled;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
        {
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            return;
        }

        handled = false;
        if (m.Msg == WM_NCHITTEST || m.Msg == WM_MOUSEMOVE)
        {
            formSize = this.Size;
            screenPoint = new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32());
            clientPoint = this.PointToClient(screenPoint);

            boxes = new Dictionary<uint, Rectangle>() {
            {HTBOTTOMLEFT, new Rectangle(0, formSize.Height - RHS, RHS, RHS)},
            {HTBOTTOM, new Rectangle(RHS, formSize.Height - RHS, formSize.Width - 2*RHS, RHS)},
            {HTBOTTOMRIGHT, new Rectangle(formSize.Width - RHS, formSize.Height - RHS, RHS, RHS)},
            {HTRIGHT, new Rectangle(formSize.Width - RHS, RHS, RHS, formSize.Height - 2*RHS)},
            {HTTOPRIGHT, new Rectangle(formSize.Width - RHS, 0, RHS, RHS) },
            {HTTOP, new Rectangle(RHS, 0, formSize.Width - 2*RHS, RHS) },
            {HTTOPLEFT, new Rectangle(0, 0, RHS, RHS) },
            {HTLEFT, new Rectangle(0, RHS, RHS, formSize.Height - 2*RHS) }
        };

            foreach (var hitBox in boxes)
            {
                if (hitBox.Value.Contains(clientPoint))
                {
                    m.Result = (IntPtr)hitBox.Key;
                    handled = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!handled)
            base.WndProc(ref m);

    }
```

the problem here when I resize the form there isn't scrollbar show how ever i set auto-scroll = true,how can I make form scroll-able?

Comment: The scrollbars will only show if a control on the form is outside the boundaries of the form. Is that so in your case ?

Comment: Yes,I have small my form too small

Comment: Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730376/how-do-you-add-a-scrollbar-to-a-panel-control-with-many-controls-in-windows-form#730456

Comment: @Baltasarq I had made my form auto scroll